# Jquery append() limit

Tags: jquery

Hi all I have this `scripts` and I want to append happen only six times

```
$(".upload_add").click(function(){
    $("#film_upload_side")
    .append('<div class="photo_upload_button"> Shoose file to upload</div>');
});
```

Comment: You want it to happen six times with one click? Or a maximum of six times with one time per click? And also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: hey if you dont know answer please don't downgrade my questions!

Comment: I certainly know an answer, you just need to learn the rules here.

Comment: I want only six click (sorry for my English)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set a counter:

```
var counter = 0;
$(".upload_add").click(function(){
    counter++;
    if(counter<7)
    $("#film_upload_side").append('<div class="photo_upload_button"> Shoose file to upload</div>');

});
```

Comment: please rate up my questions because bad people downgrade it

Comment: @user3319498 don't care about votes, we're here to help.

Comment: while copying the code from question, please make sure that you check for any spelling mistake.Even it might not be important, it will be making it as good answer :)

Answer (score 3):

```
var flag = 0;
$(".upload_add").click(function(){
    flag++;
    if(flag<=6)
    $("#film_upload_side").append('<div class="photo_upload_button"> Shoose file to upload</div>');

});
```

check flag when it becomes 6, then stop appending.